# Iptables - dstnat not working after adding implicit deny rule

Tags: port-forwarding, iptables, nat

I decided to play with iptables and I'm basically new to it yet. Trying to use it as a firewall. My goal is to port forward a RDP service from the LAN side. Here is my scenario:

ens32 is the WAN interface,
ens33 is the LAN interface,
10.9.3.1 belongs to the LAN subnet, it is the host that's RDP service should be accessed over the WAN.

My idea was the following: By the first rule, I wanted to reject all traffics in general. The second one allows the related and established connections over the WAN. The third one allows the outbound RDP traffic, and the last one is the dstnat port forwarding rule.

My problem is that if the first rule is active, then the port forwarding is not working. It only works, if I disable the reject rule. I believe, I may have skipped something. Here is my config:

```
-A PREROUTING -i ens32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.9.3.1:3389
-A FORWARD -i ens33 -s 10.9.3.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp -o ens32 -d 0.0.0.0/0 --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i ens32 -o ens33 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where's the rule that allows packets to 10.9.3.1:3389? Is this address supposed to accept RDP connections, or to initiate them, or both?

Comment: How do I define that rule to allow packets to 10.9.3.1:3389? This address supposed only to accept RDP connections. Thanks.

Comment: Since state `NEW` traffic will be coming from `ens32` (WAN) to to `ens33` (LAN), the interface matching (`-i` / `-o`) in the `ACCEPT` rules are wrong. Also `10.9.3.1` should be for `-d` not `-s` in the first `FORWARD` rule. (And `-s 0.0.0.0/0` does not need to be stated explicitly.)

Comment: Replaced that rule with this:

-A FORWARD -i ens32 -p tcp -m tcp -o ens33 -d 10.9.3.1 --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT

Still not working.

Comment: Well, I said `ACCEPT` rule*s*.